# Obtener el tamaño de un archivo de imagen

Tags: .net, web, genexus

```
GX17 u2 

.NET para WEB
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el `File.size` de una variable de tipo `Image`? .

Necesito saber como obtener el tamaño del archivo antes de subirlo en una aplicación WEB.

Mi código:

```
  for each
        where EmpresaId=1
        where ProductoStrId="1"
        &ProductoFotoPrincipal=ProductoFotoPrincipal
    endfor  
    &FileSize=&Image.FileSize
    GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Pgmname+"#&FileSize:"+&FileSize.ToString())
```

El error de compilación:

```
========== Default (C# Web) Generation started ==========
Generating to CSharpModel\web\test.cs
Generating to CSharpModel\web\test.js
Generating to CSharpModel\web\gxcfg.js
Generating to CSharpModel\web\GXCFG.WEB
Generating to CSharpModel\web\client.exe.config
Generating to CSharpModel\web\Developermenu.bld
Generating to CSharpModel\web\genexus.programs.common.bld
Generating to CSharpModel\web\library.bld
Generating to CSharpModel\web\bld15.info
Success: Default (C# Web) Generation
Compressing static files...Success
========== DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (C# Web) started ==========
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:FrameworkPath="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /v:q /m /p:GxExternalReference=GeneXus.Security.API.Common.dll "C:\kbs\PedidoCore\CSharpModel\build\LastBuild.sln"
c:\kbs\PedidoCore\CSharpModel\web\test.cs(849,25): error CS0103: El nombre 'GxImageUtil' no existe en el contexto actual [C:\kbs\PedidoCore\CSharpModel\build\test\test.csproj]
Failed: DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (C# Web)
========== Web config update started ==========
Updating web config ...
Success: Web config update
Failed: Run Test
```

Answer (score 1):

Ese error de compilación te debe estar dando porque esta Api se implementó en v17 u3. Probaría ahí o superior y sino reportaría el caso.

Documentación al respecto :
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39415,Image+manipulation+API

Saludos,

Comment: Me ocurre generando para WEB, no para móviles. Es una opción solo para generador SD? Que equivalente hay para WEB?

Comment: Que generador? Puedes copiar el error de compilación completo? Gracias

Comment: Edité el post y agregué el código utilizado y el detalle del error de compilación para ser mas explícito, gracias

Comment: En net la implementación entró en v17u3, por eso debe ser el error de compilación. Editó respuesta.No esta documentado en web, ya que esta pendiente en otros generadores.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar de asignarla a un tipo File y ahí obtener el tamaño.

```
&File.Source = &Image
&Len = &File.GetLength()
```

Por lo tanto, siguiendo tu código, lo podrías expresar de esta forma:

```
for each
    where EmpresaId=1
    where ProductoStrId="1"
    &ProductoFotoPrincipal=ProductoFotoPrincipal
endfor  
&File.Source = &ProductoFotoPrincipal
&FileSize = &File.GetLength()

GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Pgmname+"#&FileSize:"+&FileSize.ToString())
```

Comment: Por favor indica las operaciones importantes a tener en cuenta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Se editó para indicar como ejecutarlo en el código provisto en la pregunta.